# Wordpress - If Statement in variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to show 3 random categories in my posts.

I use [Advanced Custom Fieds](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to show category image. The if statement is:

```
 if ( get_field( 'portada', 'category_' . $cats->term_id ) ) {
echo '<a class="cover margin-ultimos" href="' . get_category_link( $cats->term_id ) . '">';
    echo '<div id="cover-home" class="gray-shadow">';
        echo '<img src="'. get_field( 'portada', 'category_'.$cats->term_id ). '" alt="Portada'. get_cat_name ( $cats->term_id ) . '" />';
    echo '</div>';
```

And, i'm trying to show this using [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories), so i added in **functions.php** file this lines:

```
 add_filter ( 'wp_list_categories', 'img_before_link_list_categories' );

function img_before_link_list_categories( $list ) {
  $cats = get_categories();
    foreach($cats as $cat) {

        $find = $cat->name.'</a>';
        $replace = '//Here the If Statement to show the image';
        $list = str_replace( $find, $replace, $list );

        $list = preg_replace('%<li class=".*">|</?ul>%U', '<h2>', $list);
        $list = str_replace('</li>', '</h2>', $list);
    }
 return $list;
}
```

How can save the if statement in `$replace` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$replace = '';
if( get_field( 'portada', 'category_' . $cats->term_id ) ) 
{
    $replace .= '<a class="cover margin-ultimos" href="' . get_category_link( $cats->term_id ) . '">';
    $replace .= '<div id="cover-home" class="gray-shadow">';
    $replace .= '<img src="'. get_field( 'portada', 'category_'.$cats->term_id ). '" alt="Portada'. get_cat_name ( $cats->term_id ) . '" />';
    $replace .= '</div>';
    $replace .= '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Just missing `</a>` in the last `$replace . = ...` and, thats work correclty :)

Comment: Tweaked as needed. Glad to hear it!